# Query to know the average of data in each day

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to know de average of numbers of datas in each date in august month.

**Example**

```
31-08 - 2 registers
30-08 - 3 registers
```

I tryied the follow query, but without success

```
SELECT AVG(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Chave_ID desc)), DATEPART(day, datahora) 
from San_Chave 
where DATEPART(month, datahora) = 8 
group by DATEPART(day, datahora), Chave_ID
order by DATEPART(day, datahora)  desc
```

DataHora is `DateTime` type and 
Chave_Id is `Primary Key` but the numbers aren't in a logical order, so I try to use `ROW_NUMBER()` function

Somebody can help me ?

**OUTPUT THAT I DESIRE**

```
MONTH  DAY    REGISTER
8      31     10
8      30     9
8      29     1
```

**TABLE**

To do the query I think will need just the `Chave_Id` and `DataHora`, `Chave_id` will be the numbers of registers

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[San_Chave](
    [Chave_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Usuario_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Credenciada_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Usuario_Id_Responsavel] [int] NULL,
    [DataHora] [datetime] NULL,
    [Transacao] [int] NULL,
    [Cliente_Id] [int] NULL,
    [DataHoraPegou] [datetime] NULL,
    [DataHoraDevolverPrevisao] [datetime] NULL,
    [DataHoraEntregou] [datetime] NULL,
    [HorasDevolucao] [int] NULL,
    [NomeResponsavel] [varchar](130) NULL,
    [CpfResponsavel] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [RgResponsavel] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [TelResponsavel] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Tel2Responsavel] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Endereco] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [Devolvido] [bit] NULL,
    [TextoDevolucao] [varchar](5000) NULL,
    [De] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_San_Chave] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Chave_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Surely you just need a `COUNT` rather than an average of the count?

Comment: I don't udnerstand your usage of the word `average`. Average of what, specifically?

Comment: @GarethD I don't know, maybe a count can resolve.

Comment: COUNT of number of registers that are inserted in my table `San_Chave` for each day in August month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this will give the output required

```
SELECT  CAST(DataHora AS DATE) AS [Date],
        COUNT(Chave_ID) AS [Entries]
FROM    San_Chave
GROUP BY CAST(DataHora AS DATE)
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing, without seeing your schema:

```
select Year, Month, avg(Count) as DailyAvgPerMonth
from (
    select DATEPART(year, datahora) as Year, 
        DATEPART(month, datahora) as Month, 
        count(*) as Count
    from Save_Chave
    group by DATEPART(year, datahora), 
        DATEPART(month, datahora), 
        DATEPART(day, datahora)
) a
group by Year, Month
```

Comment: Please provide data used to generate that output.